# Issue in Pagination Spring data

Tags: java, spring, pagination, cassandra, spring-data

I am trying to implement pagination in Services. Using Cassandra as a database
My code works fine if query returns some small number of list. I am just filtering out with number off pages[hardcoded as 100/ dont want to hardcode rather to return as param] and offset value. So for every request i dont want to make a query. Am sure there should be a possible way to set offset value in query itself.
My code-

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/find/customerreqbyperiod", method = RequestMethod.GET,
  produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public List<CustomerReq> findCustomerRequest(@RequestParam(value = "productid") final String pProductId,
  @RequestParam(value = "dataperiod") final String pdataPeriod,
  @RequestParam(value = "offset") final int offset)
  {
   List<CustomerReq> requestList = null;

   try
   {
    requestList = requestService.findCustomerRequest(pProductId, pdataPeriod, offset);
      if (requestList == null || offset > requestList.size()) return new ArrayList<CustomerRequestV2>();

       int numberOfItems = 10;
       int fromIndex = offset;
       int toIndex = Math.min(offset + numberOfItems, requestList.size());

        return requestList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
       }
  catch (final ServiceException e)
    {
     LOG.error(ERROR_RETRIEVING_LIST + pProductId, e);
    }
   return requestList;
  }
```

@Repository-

```
   @Query("select * from customer_request where product_id = ?0 and data_period = ?1")
   List<CustomerReq> findByProductIdAnddataPeriod(String productId, String dataPeriod, int offset);
```

Please provide your valuable Suggestion. Thank you!-Saurav

Answer (score 0):

I think you should you use `Pageable` here for example:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query("select cr from customer_request cr where cr.product_id = :productId and cr.data_period = :dataPeriod")
    Page<CustomerReq> findByProductIdAnddataPeriod(@Param("productId") String productId, @Param("dataPeriod") String dataPeriod, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And pass `PageRequest` with offset:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, offset);
Page<CustomerReq> customerReqsPage = findByProductIdAnddataPeriod("productId","datePeriod", pageRequest);
List<CustomerReq> customerReqs = customerReqsPage.getContent();
```

**UDP**:
Unfortunately it's not supported for Cassandra. JIRA ticket for that:  [jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56](http://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56)

Comment: When i tried using pageable object in my repository I was getting error-
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: neither slice nor page queries are supported yet
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)

Comment: ANy thought or solution?

Comment: Ahh probably it's not supported for cassandra. There is issue open for that https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56

Comment: Any alternate solution for this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could try devjavasource.com/cassandra/cassandra-paging-java-example but there is no solution for Spring Data for now